# useEffect is not working event after changing the dependency state

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to execute the useEffect hook when the form is submitted , given the formsubmitted as a state and when the submithandler executes I change the value of state also if the API call have some error then I set formsubmitted = false, It works for the first time I am executing, But when I am submitting the form again the useEffect is not working. Below is my Login component.
Tried consoling the formsubmitted value in useEffect hook and confirmed it is not working
And also checked whether the formSubmitted value is changing.

```
    const Authctxn = useContext(AuthContext)
  const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted]= useState(false)
  const enteredUserName = useRef('')
  const enteredPassword = useRef('')

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const { sendRequest, status, data: loginData } = useHttp(AuthAPI, false);

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(formSubmitted)
    if(formSubmitted)
    {sendRequest({'username': enteredUserName.current.value, 'password': enteredPassword.current.value})
    }
  }, [formSubmitted, enteredPassword, enteredUserName, sendRequest])
  
  const onLoginSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (
      enteredUserName.current.value.trim() !== "" &&
      enteredPassword.current.value.trim() !== ""
    ) {
      setFormSubmitted(true)
    } else {
      alert("Please fill the login details correctly");
    } 
   
  };

if(Authctxn.isLoggedIn){
  navigate('/TSBForm')
}

if(loginData &&  loginData.data && loginData.data.message &&formSubmitted) {
  setFormSubmitted(false)
  alert(loginData.data.message)
}
```

Comment: Try changing those ``useRef`` for ``useState``. useRed does not rerender the dom, so that may be why you do not after updating it.

Comment: What ***specifically*** isn't working after the submitting a subsequent time?

Comment: HI @programandoconro , Thank you for your reply , I tried using useState , but the result is same .

Comment: @DrewReese , Yeah it working for the first time i am submitting , when i am trying to submit again , then its not working...

Comment: Ok, *what* isn't working? What debugging have you done? Is the effect triggered again? (*It should if you are updating a dependency*). Is `sendRequest` called again? Is there an error? Dumping code and saying it's not working isn't a good question for SO. Can you provide us a [Minimum, Complete, and Reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I tried consoling the formsubmitted value inside useEffect, that's how i found out the useEffect is not working. and also confirmed the formsubmitted value is changing just before the useEffect line.

Comment: It is not working from second time, because you never set `formSubmitted` to false again, and you other two dependencies: `enteredPassword` & `enteredUserName` are `ref`: they never do change! try setting `formSubmitted` to `false` on every re-start, and also use `enteredPassword.current` & `enteredUserName.current` in `useEffect` hook!

Comment: Hi @ShivamJha ,thank you for reply,  I am setting the formSubmitted to false if the API do not returns token which confirmed working by consoling the value, also tried with adding ref.current, that also didn't work out well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed ,
Problem : The loginData object was not cleared after API response, so I did a clear function in my store to clear the loginData whenever the form resubmitted
Updated Code

```
const onLoginSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (
      enteredUserName.current.value.trim() !== "" &&
      enteredPassword.current.value.trim() !== ""
    ) {
      reset()
      setFormSubmitted(true)
    } else {
      alert("Please fill the login details correctly");
    }
```

Store clear Function

```
  const reset =()=> {
    dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR' });
  }
  if (action.type === 'CLEAR') {
    return {
      data: null,
      error: null,
      status: null,
    };
  }
```

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for the second time because it depends on:
-**Boolean state** (this is the one that makes it run the first time, by changing from `false` to `true`).
-**Two refs**: those won't cause the effect to run because they don't change as long as the component exists (only their `.current` value will change and you can't put them in the dependencies array anyway.
-**A function**: this won't change either.

Use **states** instead of **refs**

Comment: add code that fixes this issue